# MUIv5 and tss-react SSR issue: Unable to handle style definition reliably. ArrowFunctionExpression in CSS prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js13

I am in the process of migrating my mui to v5 and I have run into issues with the makeStyes "interpolation" pattern like below:

```
 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: (props) => {
      let bgColor = "inherit"
      if (props.colorPalette.toLowerCase() === COLORS.SAND) {
        bgColor = theme.palette.background.sand
      } else if (props.isGreenBG) {
        bgColor = theme.palette.primary.main
      } else {
        bgColor = theme.palette.common.white
      }
      return bgColor
    },
  },
  heading: {
    color: (props) => {
      if (props.isGreenBG) {
        return theme.palette.common.white
      }
      return theme.palette.primary.main
    },
    marginBottom: `15px`,
    letterSpacing: `normal`,
    [theme.breakpoints.down(`xs`)]: {
      fontSize: `2rem`,
      lineHeight: `2rem`,
    },
  },
  subhead: {
    color: (props) => {
      if (props.isGreenBG) {
        return theme.palette.common.white
      }
      return theme.palette.common.black
    },
    lineHeight: `1.5rem`,
    fontSize: `1.25rem`,
    [theme.breakpoints.down(`md`)]: {
      lineHeight: `1.125rem`,
      fontSize: `1rem`,
    },
  },
  body: {
    color: (props) => {
      if (props.isGreenBG) {
        return theme.palette.common.white
      }
      return theme.palette.text.lightHeader
    },
  },
}))

export const MyComponent = ({ colorPalette }) => {
  const isGreenBG = colorPalette.toLowerCase() === COLORS.GREEN1
  const classes = useStyles({
    isGreenBG,
    colorPalette,
  })

  // ...rest of component, for example...
  return <h1 className={classes.heading}>Just an example</h1>
}
```

I have used the code-mod and found these TODOs: // TODO jss-to-tss-react codemod: Unable to handle style definition reliably. ArrowFunctionExpression in CSS prop.

Here is what is displayed for the value in Chrome dev tools:
[image]

Is there a way to support this type of pattern with SSR? It works as expected with CSR and I can't find a solution anywhere other than a rewrite but it would be nice to maintain this functionality. Thanks!

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with supporting the functionality using tss-react, I just didn't handle every possible use case in the codemod (I mainly handled cases that occur within my own codebase). When the codemod detects a case that it knows it doesn't handle, it inserts the TODO comments. It just means you need to migrate the syntax of that case manually. Are `colorPalette` and `isGreenBG` properties/parameters that you pass to `useStyles`?

Comment: If you show a more complete code example that includes the full `makeStyles` code and how the `useStyles` gets called so that I can see where `colorPalette` and `isGreenBG` are coming from, I can show you the equivalent syntax to use for tss-react.

Comment: I figured there was nothing wrong with the code-mod, but I can't find any solution online for supporting this type of functionality with tss-react.

I am passing both of those as params to use styles, updating the above example for better context. I appreciate you taking a look at this, I was starting to think I'd just have to rewrite the logic from the ground up which wouldn't be ideal. Thanks!

Comment: I added a more complete example usage @RyanCogswell, please let me know if you would like any more details, thanks!

Comment: I've found solutions for passed params like this https://docs.tss-react.dev/api/makestyles, but they don't work as a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tss-react doesn't support functions for individual style rules or CSS props, but the main body of the `makeStyles` call is a function, so all the logic can to be moved to the top of that function.

Below is a working version of your code (though I slimmed down the styles to just `root` and `heading`). In addition to moving the function logic above the style definitions, you also need to specify the parameters after the theme in the first line of the `makeStyles` call (e.g. `(theme, { colorPalette, isGreenBG })`).

```
import { makeStyles } from "tss-react/mui";

const useStyles = makeStyles()((theme, { colorPalette, isGreenBG }) => {
  let bgColor = "inherit";
  if (colorPalette.toLowerCase() === "sand") {
    bgColor = theme.palette.background.sand;
  } else if (isGreenBG) {
    bgColor = theme.palette.primary.main;
  } else {
    bgColor = theme.palette.common.white;
  }
  const color = isGreenBG
    ? theme.palette.common.white
    : theme.palette.primary.main;
  return {
    root: {
      backgroundColor: bgColor
    },
    heading: {
      color,
      marginBottom: `15px`,
      letterSpacing: `normal`,
      [theme.breakpoints.down(`xs`)]: {
        fontSize: `2rem`,
        lineHeight: `2rem`
      }
    }
  };
});

const MyComponent = ({ colorPalette }) => {
  const isGreenBG = colorPalette.toLowerCase() === "green1";
  const { classes } = useStyles({
    isGreenBG,
    colorPalette
  });

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <h1 className={classes.heading}>Just an example</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default function Demo() {
  return <MyComponent colorPalette="green1" />;
}
```

[image: Edit makeStyles with props]

Comment: Oh man I don't know why I didn't think of that, seems so obvious after seeing it. This was a huge help, thanks a million!

Comment: Seriously, thank you. I've been working for the past week on migrating a huge library of complex components from mui v4 to v5 and this was the last roadblock.